# When creating a "Restful" webservice can standard http get & http post syntax be used?

Tags: oracle-apex, restful-architecture

We are working in the office using Oracle APEX to create some web services. After beating our heads against the wall we finally figured out that the terms get & post when talking about RESTful services are not the same as standard HTTP.

We will need to create two types of web services;

In the first, the external  application passes a few fields and the method queries a record and sends the data back to the external application.

In the second an external application builds a 30 field record that needs to be inserted by the method into the DB.

In a normal web app we would in both cases typically http post the data to to a cgi (asp, aspx, pl...) page that would parse the fields and do what needs to be done.

Since we have written the new app in APEX, and we would like to join the late 20th century, we thought we would use a web service on the provider side. The consumer will be AS3/flex/flash.

Can we still use the traditional http post and/or http get methodology of defining name=data pairs and send them to the web service?

What we have seen so far is that the data passed (at least in an APEX Restful GET) needs to be positional and not name=data pairs.

I guess the first question is where can we get some basic concepts on how to pass data using "RESTful" get & post? Something aimed at a web service dolt would be good.

Another question is if the HTTP get/post methodolgy can be used, how would it be done in Oracle APEX v5.0?

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of questions inside your post, perhaps if you narrow it down to a specific problem, you'd get better answers. I've used RESTful services with APEX 4.2, 5, 5.1 and they work just fine.

> In the first, the external application passes a few fields and the method queries a record and sends the data back to the external application.

This is typical GET request. You pass the parameters (I usually pass them as part of the URL), use them in query, and return the values. You can even pass them to PL/SQL block, do whatever processing you need, then return the results.

> In the second an external application builds a 30 field record that needs to be inserted by the method into the DB.

This is typcial POST request (although you still can use GET but not recommended). The format of how the data is being sent is important. I've done that using JSON format, and received as bind variable `:body` at APEX end. In APEX you can parse it and insert it into a table.

Few resources might help you to get going:
http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/apex/r50/Restful%20Services/restful_services.html#section1

This is especially helpful for POST:
https://ruepprich.wordpress.com/2016/03/22/apex-rest-post/

Comment: Hawk, thanks for the reply. 
 
Our lack of understanding is pretty basic. What we need to know and the links which we had previously reviewed do not seem to cover is, How do you call these services from say HTML? (ASPX, PL, ASP PHP) The terms used GET/POST do not seem to be related to the same terms in standard HTML.

Comment: We had no problem creating the APEX web service. Since I am writing the consumer, I rebelled at the syntax of http://myservice.com:8888/service/method/param1/param2/param3

Comment: @PaulStearns I have not worked on (ASPX, PL, ASP PHP), but my advice is start testing your services using general REST client tool such as [postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en). These tools are standard. Once you get the service working there, converting it to any other client would be a matter of reading the documentations.

Comment: @PaulStearns I've testing APEX services using postman, as well as Hybrid Mobile App (HTML5), and the only thing was different there is I passed the parameters in the URL between curl brackets e.g.`domain/ords/{parm1}/{parm2}/... etc'. But this is client specific and not APEX related.